# Word/phrase to describe someone skilled at using/combining raw materials to make something impressive?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for an adjective to describe someone skilled at taking raw materials and combining them and turning them into something beneficial. Relevant professions here include a cook/chef, a materials engineer, pharmaceutical scientist, perhaps even an explosives/demolition expert if they have to combine certain materials.

Originally I was thinking something like "crafty" but I feel that word also has other negative connotations.

Example: Give Joe any material or substance and he can create something great, he's so ________.

Comment: The word which comes to mind to the speaker of French I am is the verb 'concocter quelque chose', 'to concoct something', in its positive sense, which is to do with cooking, especially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oxford online gives one defintion of [artisan](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/artisan) as

> A worker in a skilled trade, especially one that involves making things by hand.

The same dictionary gives the adjectival form [artisanal](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/artisanal) as

> Relating to or characteristic of an artisan

This is probably as good a general word as you will find, particularly as terms like 'artisan bakery' are quite commonly used these days.

Answer (score 1):

How does innovative sound?

Give Joe any material or substance and he can create something great, he's so innovative.

Comment: Also good, but like inventive it doesn't quite capture the actual mixing of ingredients. A chef for example can be innovative, but so can a professional athlete; what I mean is that it isn't specific enough.

Comment: Hi Akash, welcome to EL&U. Note, the system has flagged your answer as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. It's best if you [edit] your answer to provide more information - e.g., add a published definition of *innovative* (linked to the source) and explain why it applies in this context. For further guidance, see [answer]. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have it right there (well, almost) in your example sentence. Someone who *creates* great things is ***creative***. Also, (quite synonymous) ***inventive***.

Collins:

> **[creative](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/creative)**
>
> 1. *adjective*
>      A creative person has the ability to invent and develop original ideas, especially in the arts.
>
> We will try to be creative and have one or two good ideas. Times,
>   Sunday Times (2014)
>
> **[inventive](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/inventive)**
>   *adjective*
>   An inventive person is good at inventing things or has clever and original ideas.
>
> He is inventive and resourceful with vegetables, sourcing many from a
>   walled garden 30 minutes from the restaurant. Times, Sunday Times
>   (2013)

Comment: Inventive is a great one, but I am looking for something that also captures the mixing/combing of materials aspect. For example "crafty" as as being creative/artistic also brings the idea of craft and working with different materials.

Answer (score 1):

It's a noun rather than an adjective, and it's also gendered, but 'craftsman' might work in some contexts for this. For instance, 'Give Joe any material or substance and he can create something great; he's a true craftsman'.

Comment: Definitely, crafter would also work and is gender neutral. I am hoping that an adjective does exist though.